# MySQL: Join 3 tables with distinct values

Tags: mysql, join

So I have 3 tables: tableA, tableB, tableC with structures as follows

tableA

| id | name | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ray | MD |
| 2 | Sam | LA |
| 3 | John | NY |

tableB

| id | a_id | amount | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | CHARGE |
| 2 | 2 | 20 | CHARGE |
| 3 | 3 | 70 | CHARGE |

tableC

| id | a_id | amount | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 50 | CHARGE |
| 2 | 2 | 40 | DEPOSIT |
| 3 | 1 | 60 | CHARGE |

I need the output of the join as follows:

| A id | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 3 | 70 |

So, here it calculates the sum of amount based on id in tableA. It checks the tableB for amount and if not present only then it checks tableC. Thats why the id 2 has amount 30 in output.

> But what actually happens is the sum of both tables are added. So I get amount 120 for id 2. How do I get the required output?

So I tried this query here

```sql
Select if( SUM(CASE WHEN B.code != 'DEPOSIT' 
                    THEN B.amount 
                    ELSE 0 END) > 0,
           SUM(CASE WHEN B.code != 'DEPOSIT' 
                    THEN B.amount 
                    ELSE 0 END),
           SUM(CASE WHEN C.code != 'DEPOSIT' 
                    THEN C.amount 
                    ELSE 0 END)) as total 
FROM tableA as A 
left join tableB AS B on A.id=B.a_id 
LEFT JOIN tableC AS C on A.id=C.a_id 
GROUP BY A.id
```

Comment: Please lern to format your questions after 60 posts.

Comment: Thanks. Was just checking how to do that

Comment: Your query is logically incorrect. You should see joining multiplying. See the output for `tableA.id = 2`. You should aggregate then join.

Comment: @Akina Yeah. I missed the telling the actual question

Comment: @Akina Can you further elaborate please. Didn't quite get that

Comment: *MySQL: Join 3 tables with distinct values* What do you mean while using the word "distinct"?

Comment: @Akina I mean its been 4 months. By now, the fixed issue has also been broken again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a solution like this

```
    Select A.id, SUM(if(B.amount is NOT NULL,B.amount, C.amount)) as total 
FROM tableA as A 
LEFT JOIN tableB AS B on A.id=B.a_id and B.code != 'DEPOSIT'
LEFT JOIN tableC AS C on A.id=C.a_id and C.code != 'DEPOSIT'
GROUP BY A.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```sql
SELECT id, CASE WHEN b.amount
                THEN b.amount
                ELSE c.amount
                END amount
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT a_id id, 
                   SUM( CASE WHEN code != 'DEPOSIT'
                             THEN amount
                             ELSE 0 
                             END ) amount
            FROM tableB
            GROUP BY id ) b USING (id)
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT a_id id, 
                   SUM( CASE WHEN code != 'DEPOSIT'
                             THEN amount
                             ELSE 0 
                             END ) amount
            FROM tableC
            GROUP BY id ) c USING (id)
```